# Configuring Dynamic Carrier Frequency and Bandwidth for OFDMA Implementation in INET

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am implementing Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiple Access (OFDMA) in INET and facing challenges configuring dynamic carrier frequency and bandwidth for each transmitted message. In the INET physical layer, I've modified the "*apsk*" module to pass the carrier frequency and bandwidth to the "*ApskDimensionalTransmitter*" for each packet sent from the MAC layer. However, at the receiver side, the static "*centerFrequency*" and "*bandwidth*" settings hinder the reception of dynamically transmitted packets, as they don't adapt to the changing frequency and bandwidth configurations set by the "*ApskDimensionalTransmitter*."

I've computed the dynamic carrier frequency d bandwidth for each message at the MAC layer and have successfully passed this information to the "*ApskDimensionalTransmitter*" within the "*apsk*" module at the Physical layer. However, I'm uncertain about the necessary modifications at the receiver side to enable dynamic listening to the carrier frequency and bandwidth dynamically set at the "*ApskDimensionalTransmitter*."

Which specific files or components at the receiver side should be modified or updated to ensure dynamic adaptation to the carrier frequency and bandwidth changes set by the "*ApskDimensionalTransmitter*" for successful reception?